# PreparedStatement staying null

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I am currently creating a private method inside a servlet. But my `PreparedStatement` keeps returning `null`.

```
private ArrayList<String> emails(String id) {
        ArrayList<String> email= new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement st = null;
            ResultSet data = null;
            DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test",
                    "test", "test");
            String sql = "SELECT email FROM  hdpr.email_table WHERE id='"
                    + id+ "'";
            data = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (data.next()) {
                email.add(data.getString("email"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            e.getMessage();
        }

        return email;

    }
```

Comment: You initialize it (`st`) to null and never reassign it. What do you expect?

Comment: Hi null_logic - are you satisfied with my answer or do you need some additional help? :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Try it like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> emails(String id) {
    ArrayList<String> email= new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        ResultSet data = null;

        // Creating a new connection
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test",
                "test", "test");  

        // your SQL Query now with a ? as parameter placeholder
        String sql = "SELECT email FROM  hdpr.email_table WHERE id = ?";

        // creating a new preparedStatement using your sql query
        st = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        // set the first ? to the value of id
        st.setString(1, id);

        data = st.executeQuery();
        while (data.next()) {
            email.add(data.getString("email"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return email;

}
```

#### Steps you should also have a look to:

1. If you assign `null` to a variable it will be `null` the `NullpointerException` will always occur if you try to call a method from that object.
2. To use your `PreparedStatement st` you need to initialize it by creating  preparedStatement using your connection and also your SQL query.
3. Don't add parameters to a SQL query using the `+` operator - this will open doors for **SQL Injection** for this we have the prepared statement and `setString()`, `setInt()`, ...
4. You should have a look at tutorials like let's say this: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Comment: The `executeQuery(String sql)` method is defined on `PreparedStatement`'s parent class, `Statement`, wherein in the javadocs it says, "This method cannot be called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`". You should use `st.executeQuery()` instead, which uses the SQL that was "prepared".

Comment: @dcsohl thanks! Forgot to remove the `sql` from `executeQuery()` after coping that code-block from the question.